# Ubuntu 16.04 thin fonts (com fonte bugada)

Tags: 16.04, fonts, startup

## English Translation:

Sometimes my Ubuntu 16.04 installation gets stuck on a very thin font. A reboot will sometimes fix it. How can I fix this?

## Portuguese Original Text:

Às vezes o meu ubuntu 16.04 fica com a fonte muito fina. Depois de reiniciar algumas vezes, ele volta ao normal. Como posso corrigir esse erro?

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. As this is an English speaking site and many of us don't speak Portuguese plus the Google translate is a bit ambiguous, it would be nice if you could translate your question into English.

Comment: Please delete this question.

Comment: You can delete this question by yourself. Just click on delete. Though I dont see why you should delete it.

Comment: @Bruni Gives error.

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occurs with Ubuntu starting too fast. It can be solved in two ways:

- Enable login screen (by disabling auto-login). The pause where you have to enter password at startup slows down Ubuntu.

------------------- **OR** -----------------------

- Put `sleep 1` (sleeps for 1 second, increase to 2, 3, etc if needed) command into your `/etc/rc.local` file before the `exit 0` line at the bottom.

If none of these steps work upgrade your Kernel to the latest version 4.8.4 (as of October 24, 2016).

To read these lines type: `Portuguese to English` into your google chrome search bar.

Comment: Adding "sleep 2" to the startup applications may not actually do anything - startup applications are started in parallel (at the same time), and since `sleep` does not use much CPU time, it won't delay any of the other startup programs.

Comment: @JonasCz That is a good point. I had OP problem but now have 3 extra tasks added to Startup Applications which solves it without `sleep 2` command. The bug is hard to test because it doesn't happen all the time. I think USB initialization can also slow system down.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Did not work

Comment: @GuilhermeBarbosa Sometimes unplugging USB when booting and plugging them in when finished works. The final solution would be upgrading Kernel to 4.8.4.

Comment: @GuilhermeBarbosa I changed the answer to move the sleep command from Startup Applications to rc.local. (Eu mudei a resposta para mover o comando sono dos aplicativos de inicialização para rc.local.)

Comment: @Pleasedeleteme You are welcome!